# why does ParameterizedThreadStart work without getting any parameter?

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, asynchronous, parameterized

I have a simple program which starts a thread. 
As an argument to the thread I pass a ParameterizedThreadStart delegate.
Till here all good.
Now When I start the thread, I need to pass it a required object, but suprisingly it all works well without giving it any object! How come?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(F1));
        thread.Start();  //Why does it work with out passing any argument?
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void F1(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

The program prints Hello, and I expected to get an error.

Comment: Without any parameters, the `Start` method will pass the defaults for each parameter to the method. And because you're not using `obj` nothing happens, if you debug your app and inspect it you'll see `obj` is null, instead of whatever you may pass to the method

Comment: @MindSwipe Yea I've seen it is null, but I didn't understand why.

Comment: That's because `null` is the default for every object, and because `ParameterizedThreadStart` does not accept methods that take `struct`s as parameters the start method can simply fill every parameter with `null`

Comment: @MindSwipe that's right, but you can say it about every function that suppose to get an object as parameter, but in any other function, if you don't supply the argument, C# doesn't just send a null as an argument. The compiler will fail the program. However In this case, C# sends null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the [Thread.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Thread_Start_System_Object_) overload that takes a paramete: Eg:

```
thread.Start("Hello world");
```

The [Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Thread_Start) method you are calling will cause `null` to be passed to the thread function:

> If this overload is used with a thread created using a
>   ParameterizedThreadStart delegate, null is passed to the method
>   executed by the thread.

Comment: Hi, Yes I know it. Please read the question again. I ask why does it work without passing it any argument.

Comment: May you please direct me to a formal source for "The Start method you are calling will cause null to be passed to the thread function" ? Does Start() just send a null to the method?

Comment: @SItzik- I've added a quote from the MSDN documentation for `Start`, along with a link to the zero-parameter overload where you'll find the quote in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaivour. Start will call the method with it's parameters, and if it doesn't get any, it will call the method with `null` as the parameters ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Thread_Start)). And because you're not using your `obj` in any way that could cause an exception in its default, nothing is throwing an exception.

In your example, `obj` will always be null, but because you're not doing anything with it, it won't throw an exception. Lets try this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(F1));
    thread.Start();  // Will throw a null reference exception
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void F1(string obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("String passed has a length of: " + obj.Length);
}
```

This will throw a null reference exception, because the default of `string` is null. Where as this:

```cs
thread.Start("Hello World");
```

will print `String passed has a length of: 11`

Answer (score 1):

Your code must work and pass `null` value to the method `F1`. This behaviour is documented in the [`MSDN Thread.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Thread_Start):

> If this overload is used with a thread created using a
>   `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate, `null` is passed to the method
>   executed by the thread.